# Power law data fitting is not correct

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, power-law

What I'm doing wrong while trying to fit the following data, with logarithmic y-axis. The code and the produced graph are below.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.array([88.08064516, 264.24193548, 440.40322581, 616.56451613, 792.72580645, 968.88709677, 1145.0483871, 1321.20967742, 1497.37096774, 1673.53225806, 1849.69354839, 2025.85483871, 2202.01612903, 2378.17741935, 2554.33870968, 2730.5, 2906.66129032, 3082.82258065, 3258.98387097, 3435.14516129, 3611.30645161, 3787.46774194, 3963.62903226, 4139.79032258, 4315.9516129, 4492.11290323, 4668.27419355, 4844.43548387, 5020.59677419, 5196.75806452, 5372.91935484, 5549.08064516])
y = np.array([210737, 2175, 514, 158, 90, 46, 27, 22, 10, 11, 3, 7, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,1])
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
ax.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'g--')
ax.plot(x,  y, 'ro', label='data')

ax.set_yscale('log')  # I need to have the y-axis logarithmic
plt.show()
```

Comment: What function are you using for `curve_fit`? Does it come from a package or did you write it yourself?

Comment: Sorry , it's from from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

Comment: So I'm guessing the problem are the `popt` values after performing the fit. Can you print them please?

Comment: `pcov` contains a lot of `inf` I guess.

Comment: Yeah, mostly `popt` in fact.

Comment: Yes, you're right (I was printing only popt and it seem ok).
popt = [1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 6.68159466e+03]
pcov = [[inf inf inf]
 [inf inf inf]
 [inf inf inf]]
What can I do wiyh all this inf to solve the problem?

Comment: It helps because `curve_fit` somehow _likes_ to operate on a normalized range.  But I've deleted my comment because now I see that your data looks like an exponential of negative argument _in the logarithmic plot_ !!!  You'll have a better luck if you try a different  function for your fit

Comment: E.g., from `ln(y) = a exp(-(b x)) + c` we have (that is, Emacs' `calc` has) `y = exp(c + a exp(-(b x)))`, you can try to fit this double exponential, can't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is very challenging to fit without an initial guess. So add provide the guess when calling `curve_fit` as `p0` (as described in the docs):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

x = np.array([88.08064516, 264.24193548, 440.40322581, 616.56451613, 792.72580645, 968.88709677, 1145.0483871, 1321.20967742, 1497.37096774, 1673.53225806, 1849.69354839, 2025.85483871, 2202.01612903, 2378.17741935, 2554.33870968, 2730.5, 2906.66129032,3082.82258065, 3258.98387097, 3435.14516129, 3611.30645161, 3787.46774194, 3963.62903226, 4139.79032258, 4315.9516129, 4492.11290323, 4668.27419355, 4844.43548387, 5020.59677419, 5196.75806452, 5372.91935484, 5549.08064516])
y = np.array([210737, 2175, 514, 158, 90, 46, 27, 22, 10, 11, 3, 7, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,1])

p0 = [20000,0.003,1]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=p0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'g--', label = 'fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
ax.plot(x,  y, 'ro', label='data')
```

Output:

[image]

Note this helps you to troubleshoot the problem. You still have to implement the logarithmic axis. For log. fitting I would advise pruning the data like,

```
y_pruned = np.where(y<1, 1, y)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, np.log(y_pruned), p0=p0)
ax.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'g--', label = 'fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
ax.plot(x,  np.log(y_pruned), 'ro', label='data')
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I've tried and the output was the desired one. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandraBradan But be aware, the original data may be a double exponential. The initial decay is quite fast (u can quickly check this by looking at 1/e in the plot and see if x and y match there).

Comment: What method did you use to determine the initial parameters you supplied in this answer?

Comment: @JamesPhillips `a` and `c` can be extracted by visual inspection from the y values. `b` I have guessed by looking at the steep decay between the first and second point of the graph.

Comment: @Fourier, you're suggesting to try def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c * np.exp(d * x) with curve_fit?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thank you, I BTW looked at your outstanding online curve fitting tool,  keep up the good work!

Comment: @AlexandraBradan Do not over-fit the problem, if the data comes from a process that does not have two distinct rates of decay, then go for the single exponential.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do with your data is to scale both sets of data values by a logarithm and then try to fit them with the function. I included the code and the graph below.[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.array([88.08064516, 264.24193548, 440.40322581, 616.56451613, 792.72580645, 968.88709677, 1145.0483871, 1321.20967742, 1497.37096774, 1673.53225806, 1849.69354839, 2025.85483871, 2202.01612903, 2378.17741935, 2554.33870968, 2730.5, 2906.66129032, 3082.82258065, 3258.98387097, 3435.14516129, 3611.30645161, 3787.46774194, 3963.62903226, 4139.79032258, 4315.9516129, 4492.11290323, 4668.27419355, 4844.43548387, 5020.59677419, 5196.75806452, 5372.91935484, 5549.08064516])
y = np.array([210737, 2175, 514, 158, 90, 46, 27, 22, 10, 11, 3, 7, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,1])

x = np.log(x)
y = np.log(y + 1) # Need to add something to make log work

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
ax.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'g--')
ax.plot(x,  y, 'ro', label='data')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution too!

Answer (score -1):

All of the code is actually working. See the below image, I ran your code but didn't put the scaling in the y-axis before plotting. You can see that the line is actually fit except the first point it quite an outlier. The way to fix this is to first scale the y-values before fitting the function. Try that, let us know if you need more help.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the first point it'd definitely an outlier but in order to make the y axis readable I want a logarithmic scale on it

Comment: @JamesPhillips you misinterpret what I am trying to say, I just showed that the code from the question produces a 'decent' fit which is made to look much worse because the y-axis is scaled logarithmicly. I didn't suggest a new solution so obviously I know it doesn't fit the data well. Also, see how the author agrees that the first point is an outlier. Sure, it does fit the curve that is created after log scaling, but clearly in this image one point doesn't look like the others, see definition of outlier (a person or thing situated away or detached from the main body or system).

Comment: Delete it if you'd like. I would argue that this does answer the question. The question is 'What am I doing wrong?' referring to the title 'power law data fitting is not correct.' My answer posits that the power law data fitting is correct and I point out that what the author might be doing wrong is apply scaling which makes the power law scaling look incorrect. Thus, I answered the question. I mean the author got their answer from someone else, so by all means delete this.